# Blazor MatTable Page size change

Tags: blazor, matblazor

I am using pagesize for no of row in the page but that not wotking

declare without ""

```
<MatTable Items="project" FilterByColumnName="Name" PageSize="12">
```

Need to change the number of rows per page in the table

Comment: Incomplete and unclear. When do you nedd to change it? runtime?

Comment: It could be just `PageSize="@pageSize"`

Comment: <MatTable PageSize=@pagesize Items="projects" >  declare int pagsize = 10; but 5 rows only display per page

Comment: It is a known issue. it's reported on GitHub. Not much to do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is now fixed with last version. Should set it to respect the Enum (5,10,25,50,*) or it will not be displayed in the pagesize selection selectlist although it will work and display the exact number of rows you set.